# ¿Es correcto decir que un grupo musical está «girando el mundo»?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, vocabulario-técnico

Hace unas horas he escuchado en la radio a un locutor español mencionar que un grupo de música estaba «girando el mundo».
Entiendo que se refería a que estaban «de gira por el mundo». Sé que el verbo «girar» se utiliza en el mundillo del espectáculo como sinónimo de «ir de [gira](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JCyHP4L)» l, aunque sea un uso no recogido por la RAE (aún).

Mi pregunta es: **¿es correcto este uso *transitivo* del verbo?**
Hasta ahora pensaba que este uso era solo intransitivo, es decir, que uno puede «girar por Europa» o «estar girando por toda Sudamérica», pero no «girando el mundo». ¿Quizá es una mala traducción del inglés *«touring the world»*, que sí que es transitivo?

Comment: Puedes decir que giras el mundo en torno a ti (todo depende del sistema de referencia, el movimiento es relativo, ya sabes), pero de ahí a equipararlo con estar de gira, me parece aún demasiado forzado como para aceptarlo. Mucho mejor "girando por el mundo".

Comment: Curiosidad que solo tiene que ver tangencialmente con tu pregunta: veo en Covarrubias una definición de "gira" que hoy ya se ha perdido: "comida y siesta que se hace entre amigos, con regocijo y contento, juntamente con abundancia de comer y beber, y mucha alegría y chacota". Y en el Autoridades: "banquete espléndido que se hace entre amigos, con regocijo, bulla y chacota". Es decir, en el siglo XVII te podías ir de gira, pero de otra forma. ¿Habrá afectado esta acepción al actual "irse de gira"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sin conocer el contexto de la frase completa diría que es un poco forzado: si dices que alguien está "*girando el mundo*" vendría a significar que literalmente está haciendo girar el planeta, como si fuera un balón, por poner un ejemplo.

De forma habitual se suelen escuchar:

- estar de gira: "*los Rolling están de gira por Europa*" (como bien dices tú)
- o hacer una gira: "*la banda de Springsteen está haciendo una gira por los Estados Unidos*", y en este caso sí sería transitivo, pero usando el verbo hacer.

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: En "touring the world" es importante lo extensa de la gira, que abarca varios continentes. Entonces se agrega el adjetivo *mundial*, por ejemplo: _hacer una gira mundial_, _girar por el mundo entero_, _estar de gira a nivel mundial_.